# What company will do, if I send their offer letter to another company

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, salary, job-offer, human-resources

I got offer from company A with 100% hike of current salary. I got second offer from company B with 50% hike of current salary. During salary negotiation with company B, I have sent the company A offer letter to company B. But company B is ready to give not more than 50% hike of current salary.   But I accepted company B offer as back up option. I am going to join in company A.

If I will not joined with company B, Will company B expose myself to company A, where I have sent company A offer letter to company B for salary negotiation.

If it is happened so, will company A revoke my offer with them ?

Comment: Why would you do this? In an attempt to get Company B to make you a comparable offer? Why would you not just tell them? If they're unwilling to make a comparable offer based on your conversation with them, then showing them the offer letter is unlikely to change anything. What you've done is potentially put the offer at Company A at risk if they were to find out you showed their offer letter to another organization.

Comment: Did big mistake. As a result it is going to cost my both offers in the end.

Comment: I accepted both offers. I wish to join A. I will kept B as backup option for A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending on an offer letter specifically isn't something I'd do. You can disclose the salary you've received elsewhere if you want to use that in negotiations (this is normal), but the actual letter may well be considered a confidential document by company A, so they may not take too kindly to you passing it around.

Chances are nothing will come of it unless you're applying to an industry where secrecy and confidentiality are considered paramount (in which case company B might think "this guy passes documents around without a second thought, do we really want to be hiring him?"), but I still wouldn't consider it best practice.

Comment: Will it cost my offer with company A ?

Comment: No-one can say for certain, but in my experience you'd be rather unlucky if that was the case.

Answer (score 4):

It's extremely bad form to send documents from one company to another without express permission. You should have just mentioned the amount. Most correspondence like this would be clearly marked for the intended recipient only. But even if it's not, that's just an 'understood'.

Whether they will revoke the offer over it is unknown. But I would, because you just made some of my financial details public knowledge, possibly to a competitor and I'd be very reluctant to employ someone who has proven themselves to have bad judgement in that area.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, informing a company during salary negotiations that you have an offer from another company who are willing to pay more is **perfectly normal**. Doing so by sending them the actual offer letter is a bit weird, but I don't see the harm in it.

I see no reason for Company B to tell Company A that you sent them the offer letter, and even if they did, I see no reason Company A would do anything about it. You've already accepted their offer because Company B can't match their terms. It would come off as incredibly petty of Company B.